# how to set manage_pages permission to a particular facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

how i can set a manage_pages permission of my application to a particular page only. Now my application get permission to manage all pages of fb user.. How i can restrict this and get permission to access a specific page only ?

I am using one simple authentication method.

```
$app_id     = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$my_url     = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxx/facebook?client=params';

$code        = $_REQUEST["code"];

//auth user
if(empty($code)) {
$dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
                . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url).'&scope=offline_access,read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages';
                echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
            }

//get user access_token
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
            . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
            . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
            . '&code=' . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);


am using the above code for authentication. when i try to print the $_REQUEST params, i couldnt find any variable names 'signed_request'.  is any other method can we use with the above code..??
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's not possible. Very annoying but well.. it's facebook so there's nothing else to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this from your side. Facebook will send you the page id in the `signed_request` so you can verify the page and show/disable content:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_REQUEST["signed_request"])) {
    $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
    $data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], $app_secret);

    if (isset($data["page"])) {
        echo $data["page"]["id"];
    } else {
        echo "Not in a page";
    }
}

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

This code is taken from [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5587784/how-can-i-find-out-what-page-has-installed-my-facebook-canvas-app/5592506#5592506) answer. Just check the `$data["page"]["id"]` against the one you want.